# pgadmin unable to autenticate localhost user in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I just installed Postgresql and PgAdmin in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and I'm trying to add local server to PgAdmin, but I'm getting this error:

[image]

These are my settings in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Are you sure you got the password right? How did you set it when installing postgres?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It actually can't authenticate any user, not only postgres

Comment: Can you connect to the database using any other tool, e.g. `psql`?

Comment: yes, that's how I created the users and set the passwords, and I have verified PostgreSQL service is up

Comment: To your question add answers to: 1) What version of `pgAdmin`?  2) What version of Postgres? 3) What  `psql` connection string did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by uninstalling PostgreSQL and pgadmin, and installing them back. I tried several guides, but this is [the only one that worked](https://www.tecmint.com/install-postgresql-and-pgadmin-in-ubuntu/).